# Accessing and assigning policies inside a policy initiative in Azure using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

I have a policy initiative in Azure, consisting of multiple policies, say 30 of them together. I mean inside the policy initiative, there are 30 policies. Now, owing to terraform's azurerm_policy_set_definition, (or we can assume the policy initiative definition to already exist as well) the entire policy initiative set can be assigned using the policy_assignment block where one can pass :

```
resource azurerm_policy_assignment "polassgn1" {
    ...
    policy_definition_id = "link_to_policy_set_initiative"
    ...
}
```

Now my question is, what if I want to assign selectively among these total of 30 policies in the initiative based on some condition...for example I wish to exclude some 5 policies, (all of their separate ids are present in the initiative). I'm new to terraform and thus, it may be said that I'm looking for a kind of an "IN" equivalent w.r.t other programming languages.

> Like talking of a "pythonic way", if we had an array of numbers L=[ 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 200 ], we can access elements of this array as L[i] and check a number,x for existence in the array through "*if x ***in*** L*"...

In a similar way, could anyone please help me on whether policies which are members of a policy initiative set, can be accessed individually in Terraform ( for instance like in a loop through an array ) and then deployed to azure through a policy_assignment block if they meet a set of conditions ?

Comment: Can you provide example of your `azurerm_policy_set_definition`? You have thirty sets?

Comment: Hii @Marcin...there exists a single policy initiative in azure and it has 30 policies defined therein. And when I pass the id of that initiative to the assignment block, the entire initiative gets assigned with 30 inside.I now want to access each of these 30 individually.

Comment: @Marcin, it may also be thought that the policy initiative pre-exists like we really don't need to write a azurerm_policy_set_definition for it at the moment. My doubt is regarding assignment and while the entire initiative gets assigned with a single policy_assignment block, my question is can we assign selectively...like a hypothetically desired subset of the 30 policies belonging to the initiative ?

Comment: Just like policy initiatives in azure are a group or collection of policies, I want to access each them individually using terraform in a kind of a loop based mechanism, is that possible @Marcin